# Ruby: is_a? and instance_of? in BasicObject

Tags: ruby, introspection, delegation

How do is_a? and instance_of? methods work with a subclass of BasicObject ?

```
class My < BasicObject
  DELEGATE = [:is_a?, :instance_of?]
  def method_missing(name, *args, &blk)
    superclass unless DELEGATE.include? name
    ::Kernel.send(name,*args, &blk) 
  end
end

my = My.new
my.is_a? BasicObject  #=> true
my.is_a? My           #=> false ???
my.instance_of? My    #=> false ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can steal `is_a?` from `Kernel`:

```
class My < BasicObject
  define_method(:is_a?, ::Kernel.method(:is_a?))
end

m = My.new
m.is_a?(My)          #=> true
m.is_a?(BasicObject) #=> true
m.is_a?(Object)      #=> false
```

If you're going to build your own object hierarchy, you could also define your own `Kernel`, something like:

```
module MyKernel
  [:is_a?, :instance_of?, :class].each do |m|
    define_method(m, ::Kernel.method(m))
  end
end

class My < BasicObject
  include ::MyKernel
end
```

Comment: Good idea of the MyKernel, it was what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`::Kernel.send(name,*args, &blk)` calls the method `name` on the class `Kernel` with the arguments `args` and the block `&blk`.

When you run `my.is_a? My` `name` is `:is_a?`, `*args` is `My`, and `&blk` is `nil`. You're really running `Kernel.is_a? My`.

Instead, if you want to reimplement `is_a?` for `BasicObject` you can walk your class's `ancestors`...

```
  def is_a?(target)
    # I don't know how to get the current class from an instance
    # that isn't an Object, so I'm hard coding the class instead.
    return ::My.ancestors.include?(target)
  end
```

Comment: You could use [Module#<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-3C) in your definition of `is_a?`..